# Parsing cell coordinates and applying to a list of data

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I have an excel grid on currencies, the x and y axis are the same.
EG:

```
    GBP, USD, EUR
GBP
USD
EUR
```

Data goes into the cell in the grid for each "pair":

eg:

```
    GBP, USD, EUR
GBP       9     7
USD  10        11
EUR  12   8
```

In my grid the horizontal headers start at `B1` and the row headers start at `A2`.

The data that goes into the grid is parsed in from a large list and the figures are saved in a dictionary:

EG:

```
dict = {'GBPUSD': '9', 'GBPEUR: '7', etc}
```

I somehow need to parse in the empty excel grid so I can write the correct value into the correct cell. The dictionary of data won't be ordered for example the first value might go in cell `B7` and the third might go in cell `Z13`.

I currently have a hard coded dictionary of x and y cell coordinates which is obviously a really bad way of doing it.

Is there a way to parse it in and save it and then write the data into the correct cell?

(I am currently writing it out as a CSV but if there is a better way then please feel free to use that, avoiding non-native libraries would be useful too)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is really useful for this, although non-native.

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'GBPUSD': '9', 'GBPEUR': '7'}

# first create an empty pandas dataframe with columns and index as specified
currencies = ['GBP', 'USD', 'EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=currencies, columns=currencies)

# now you can parse the values from the dictionary and set them as values in
# the dataframe
for key, value in dict.items(): # iteritems() in python 2.7
    idx, col = key[:3], key[3:]
    df.set_value(idx, col, int(value))

# and finally write it all to an excelfile
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```